# Dynamically resolving json property at run time using pointer string

Tags: c#, json

Say I have the following object

```
{
"Dog": {
    "Puppies": [
        {
            "Name": "John"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Alex"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Ashley"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Say I have the following string

`var savePath = "[Dog][Puppies][1]";`

If I have the above JSON object in a C# `dynamic` what would the cleanest way of replacing the puppy at index 1 be?

I can't simply do `dynamicDog.Dog.Puppies[1] = myNewPuppy` because in my situation I have no way of knowing for sure if `Puppies` will always be in that parent node. They could be nested even deeper say in `[Dog][Backpack][0][Puppies]`. The `savePath` here has the direct location of my puppy but in string form hence the need to some how resolve this string at runtime. I thought about serializing the JSON to a string and taking a stab at using `IndexOf` and all those string manipulation methods to solve the issue but that seems too hairy. *note I am not really using puppies or dogs in my actual code*

**Update to Provide more Context**

We have a project which uses JSON documents in CouchDB as "Templates" to dynamically generate Razor Views. Each DOM element that is an input gets an attribute added to it `savepath`. This `savepath` is literally the path in the JSON string that this input is built from. In most of our code we have `JS` that intercepts a form submission, creates a new JSON object using these `savepath`s and simply submits a JSON string to a controller which updates the document in CouchDb. In my situation I have a table of Puppies where a user can add an extra `Puppy` using a partial view Popup. This partial view popup has a C# POCO as a viewmodel (**A single Puppy with a single property: Name**). In order to save the puppy in the correct location in the JSON document I am passing in the `savepath` value in the submission. The main problem here is different `Dog`s may have their `Puppies` in different nodes. They may be more nested, they may be less nested. In my controller I retrieve the original `Dog` JSON document from couch and have to then add this new `Puppy` to it. Again the problem is one `Dog` can have his in the first Node `[Dog][Puppies][0]` while another `Dog` could have `[Dog][Backpack][Puppies][0]` There is no other way to tell except from that `savepath` string

Comment: I think the cleanest way here would be to use an `Expression` instead of a `string`. That is strongly typed, can be stored in a list and passed around in much the same way as your string, and can easily be used to modify or retrieve your desired node given an instance of your root node.

Comment: So assuming you had a `Dog` object. You could have `Action<Dog, Puppy> path1 = (d, p) => d.Puppies[1] = p;` and `Action<Dog, Puppy> path2 = (d, p) => d.Backpack[0].Puppies[1] = p;`. Then you could use `path1(myDog, myNewPuppy)` to replace the puppy at `path1`, or `path2(myDog, myNewPuppy)` to replace the puppy at `path2`.

Comment: Where are your path strings coming from? Are they defined in your code?

Comment: I agree. Our situation makes that virtually impossible. Imagine razor forms being dynamically built using JSON documents as 'templates'. When a user submits a form a piece of JS intercepts it, builds the JSON object and submits that to the controller which then gets saved to CouchDb. I am in turn working on another part of the site that uses actual FormCollection submission and am passing in the save path as a string because I don't have to save the whole document. I just have to update this property :/

Comment: As far as the actions go would I not have to create one for every possible scenario? Backpacks 1, 2, 3,4,5 or puppies 1,2,3,4,5. I would end up with tons of actions.

Comment: Up until "which then gets saved to couch", there doesn't seem to be anything that indicates you can't use the approach I suggested. You can have completely dynamic path expressions and completely dynamic JSON documents (by dynamic I mean constructed and resolved at runtime, not untyped). I'm not entirely clear on the "`FormCollection` submission" bit.

Comment: You would have to create *at most* as many actions as you have strings, but you could actually create a lot less. For example, whereas you would have to have two separate strings to represent `path1 = "[Dog][Puppies][1]"` and `path2 = "[Dog][Puppies][2]"`, you could have `Action<Dog, int, Puppy> replacePuppyAtIndex = (d, i, np) d.Puppies[i] = np;` and then use `replacePuppyAtIndex(myDog, 1, newPuppy);` or `replacePuppyAtIndex(myDog, 2, newPuppy);`.

Comment: I'll update my question to have a bit more information. What I meant by FormCOllection submission was a little off. I meant I was using C# POCOs in a more typical MVC fashion.

Comment: I updated my question. If you have the time to look at it hopefully that explains a little more. I understand it's hard to see without code but polluting the question with tons of code won't help either

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".